# Is there a way to tell R to use a specific .dll for OpenBLAS when I don't have read/write access to R directory?

Tags: r, openblas

I can follow the following instructions for my home computer fine.
https://github.com/david-cortes/R-openblas-in-windows

Which basically involves copying the compiled .dll for OpenBLAS into the R directory. But for work stuff, I am on a server where I don't have read/write access to the R directory. Is there any way I can place those .dll files in a personal folder, than tell R to use them as default Matrix library?

Thanks!